# Using a PHP date to fetch records from certain dates from the database

Tags: php, sql, datetime, zend-framework2

I'm trying to fetch records from today back through a month ago from my SQL db. I take the current date in PHP and the date a month ago and try to pass them to my SQL query. Unfortunately, I don't have a say in what format the date is in the database, so I definitely have to convert the dates.

I thought I had it figured out, but apparently not.

```
public function successRate()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select){
        $now    = date('y-m-d h:m:s');
        $then   = date('y-m-d h:m:s', strtotime('-1 month'));
        $select->where("enddate between convert(datetime, '" . $then . "') and convert(datetime, '" . $now . "')");
    });
    return $resultSet;
}
```

All of this stuff is helpers from the framework, nevermind about that, but what I'm trying to figure out is the query on line 6 - after "$select->where(".

I ran this query in the database itself and it worked:

```
select * from jobhistory where enddate between convert(datetime, '2013-05-20 00:00:00') and convert(datetime, '2013-06-20 00:00:00')
```

But the query in my PHP function gives this error:

'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

I know my $then and $now variables are strings, but I thought the convert business in the query is supposed to be taking care of that already? What am I missing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You say "Unfortunately, I don't have a say in what format the date is in the database". What format is the datetime? What database is it?

Comment: The datatype is datetime in a SQL Server database. Dates are stored as d-m-y h:m:s, but the query works with y-m-d h:m:s if run directly in the database.

Comment: Then you need to query the database with d-m-y h:m:s format. Otherwise you get a conversion error with certain dates.

Comment: Have you tried `echo "enddate between convert(datetime, '" . $then . "') and convert(datetime, '" . $now . "')";` to verify this string is outputting what you want?

Comment: Hm, I have thought about that, but don't rightly know how to. The query is part of a Select object in my model, so it's a bit hard to pass it to my view and echo it. I could try though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$now    = date('y-m-d h:m:s');
$then   = date('y-m-d h:m:s', strtotime('-1 month'));
```

Should be

```
$now    = date('y-m-d h:i:s');
$then   = date('y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('-1 month'));
```

Notice the `i` for minutes. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Also, according to your comment, it should be

```
$now    = date('d-m-Y h:i:s');
$then   = date('d-m-Y h:i:s', strtotime('-1 month'));
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer. [PHP: date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) will show you what characters provide what part of the date format. The original string was trying to insert the month in the minutes spot.

Comment: Absolutely right, of course. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @vanamerongen You're welcome, but reading the manual does help :)